# Is there a way to schedule Storage Backups/Syncing between 2 firebase projects Using Node.js Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to sync the videos, images, etc. from the STORAGE of a firebase project to the storage of another firebase project.
The way to approach that is to follow the instructions in this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data
However, the instructions in this link are for firestore database and not for the STORAGE.

I am trying to **schedule Storage Backups/Syncing** between 2 firebase projects Using **Node.js Cloud Functions**. Very similar to the following YouTube video, but I need to do that for the STORAGE and not for the firestore database.
[youtube.com/watch?v=HYOR42pYYzo&ab_channel=JonnyBCodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYOR42pYYzo&ab_channel=JonnyBCodes)

**Please note that it is about the STORAGE and not the firestore database.**

Thanks in advance for your support :)

Comment: Did you see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+storage+copy+files+from+one+bucket+to+another?

Comment: @Programming Gym. Can you please let us know if the above documentation helps you?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
Thank you guys for trying to help me with that.
I am trying to schedule Storage Backups/Syncing between 2 firebase projects Using Cloud Functions.
Very similar to the following video, but for the STORAGE and not for the firestore database.:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYOR42pYYzo&ab_channel=JonnyBCodes

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty